Select criteria in cell and the below cell enter amount, then transfer amount to the second sheet
I am looking for a formula which will identify a criteria in B7=text and in B8=number, I have created a spreadsheet with two sheets, "Data" and "Entry" in the "Entry" (like a summary report) sheet I have column headings such as Food, Petrol, etc, in this formula, when you select pulldown "Food" in Data sheet B7 and then enter an amount in dollars in B8 in the Data tab. The amount would go to Entry Tab under the column titled "Food".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am creating a database with a Drop Down selection in B7, then in B8 there is a dollar value. I have used this formula  =IF($B$7="Coles",$B$8,"0") the answer is recorder in another cell B24, but when I change the drop down to select another selection like House the answer would appear in B25 and the information in B24 changes to a 0 where i need to keep all the information to transfer to another sheet

Clarify your question by using the [edit]  button on the bottom of your question. Comments can get deleted over time.

It sounds like you want an Excel PivotTable.  For this to work, all the information has to be in columns like B and C. If the category text ("Food") repeats several times, with amounts next to them in column C, you create a Pivot Table on the Entry tab, then tell it where to find the Data entry table.  It has to be a list of expenses, not just two cells B7 B8. You can copy the B7 pulldown choices to the whole B column to make sure only those allowed text values are used.
If you need to keep other cells for other functions in that area, then you might need VBA and a button to copy (insert) each new entry pair into an intermediate table (like the above B:C range), and then use the pivottable for the results.  I presume that you are using Data Validation functions "List"




Pivot tables are live, and so are cells.  If you want to remember previous values, you need to save them somewhere.
